# No audio after upgrading to 5.15.0-60-generic kernel on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04

Audio output shows "Dummy Output" after running normal system updates on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  If I use grub to drop back to the 5.15.0-58 everything works normally.  Can anyone tell me why this happening and what I need to do restore audio functionality?

Comment: You can report a bug (regression) in this kernel. This is something related to your specific device.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my system was missing the linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-60 package.  I downloaded and installed this package and full audio functionality was restored.